# A case where the Euler-Lagrange equations produces $1=0$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, functional-calculus

As a reference, I asked the same question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/561449/equations-of-motions-of-mathcall-phi-x-phix) in the physics community but I am interested in the mathematical reason why this produces $1=0$.

Suppose a Lagrangian of this form

$$
L[f,x]=f[x] \tag{1}
$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

The Euler-Lagrange equations are:

$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu f)}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}$$

There are no derivates of $f$, thus the left-most term is equal to zero:

$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu f)}=0$$

Finally, the right-most term is:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}=1
$$

Thus, the result is $1=0$. Now, I am just overall skeptical of the whole thing; why is it that the Euler-Lagrangian equation able to produce a contradiction? I suspect that $L[f,x]=f[x]$ violates one of the assumptions used to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations?

Comment: What do the $[]$ mean?

Comment: @Plop Equivalent to parenthesis (so that I don't confuse functions with multiplication). For instance, if I write $f(x)=x$, then I can't compile if it means $fx=x\implies fx/x=1\implies f=1$, or if its means $f$ is a function of $x$. By using brackets for functions and parenthesis for orders of operations exclusively, the ambiguity is removed.

Comment: I'm not so sure I follow why $\partial L/ \partial f = 1$?

Comment: @vectorbundle I am working under the assumption that $\partial f[x] / \partial f[x]$ means that I can replace the variables $f[x]$ by, say $y$ then I get $\partial y / \partial y$ which equals $1$, thus $\partial f[x]/\partial f[x]=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution $f$ to the E.L equations is an stationary point of the action $ S = \int_a^b L[f]dx = \int_a^b f dx $. The E.L equations in this case admit no solution, as there is no stationary point of this functional.

Comment: So, essentially, the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation assumes that a stationary solution exists. Then, me getting $1=0$ is a side effect of violating this assumption when I attempted to solve the problem by using said Euler-Lagrange equation for a system that has no such stationary solution?

Comment: Yes. It's just like looking for the stationary points of $f(x) = x$. The equation $f'(x) = 0$ implies $1 = 0$, a contradiction. This is because $f$ has no stationary points. The EL equations only apply at the stationary point of a functional.